The probability of a lottery eventually wins
Suppose there is a gamble, and there are two lotteries. If in each round, only one of these three cases can happen:
(1) lottery A gets one score, with the probability of $1/3$;
(2) lottery B gets one score, with the probability of $1/4$;
(3) neither of them gets a score, with the probability of $5/12(=1-1/3-1/4)$,
If the lottery wins one score first can win this gamble, what are the eventual winning probabilities of lotteries A and B, respectively?
This question may sound silly, but I just learned a little about probability theory. So, I would really appreciate it if you could do me a favour.

You can ignore case 3 as it just puts you back at the start, so scale up the other two probabilities to sum to $1$

You are supposed to first edit in whatever efforts you have made, even if they have proved  to be infructuous.

"infructuous"??

@GerryMyerson: $\approx$ unfruitful

@RossMillikan Hi, can it be formulated as a Markov chain problem?

Absolutely.  There are only three states, the start and the results of case 1 and 2.  The other two are absorbing.  Case 3 leads back to start.  You have the transition probabilities.

@RossMillikan I see. Many thanks!
